# PDFBox change color of a line

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I work with pdfbox 1.8.5 and I try to draw a colored Line using `PDPageContentStream.drawLine()`.

I tried it with `PDPageContentStream.setNonStrokingColor( 255, 0, 0 );` but it doesn't work. I also didn´t find any examples or HowTos concerning Line Color.

Does anyone know, how I can change the Line Color?

Comment: Drawing a line is a Stroking operator, so NonStroking commands do nothing. Have you tried the obvious [setStrokingColor](http://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/1.8.5/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/util/operator/SetStrokingColor.html)?

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. PDPageContentStream.setStrokingColor( 255, 0, 0 ); solved it. I didn´t know the differences. Is there any documantation where I can find such things?

Comment: The difference between Stroke and Fill goes right back to the precursor of the PDF internal format -- PostScript. Read the Graphics chapter in [Adobe's PDF Reference](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html).

Comment: Annoyingly, the [API doc](http://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/1.8.12/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/edit/PDPageContentStream.html#drawLine(float,%20float,%20float,%20float)) of `PDFPageContentStream.drawLine` says: "Draw a line on the page **using the current non stroking color** and the current line width.". That's apparently wrong...

Comment: @Jesper I have modified the javadocs (not online, repository only). Thanks for pointing this out. Everybody: if you find such things, even if minor, please create an issue or mention it in the user mailing list.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try this method. It's working for me.

```
contentStream.setStrokingColor(229, 13, 209);
```

Answer (score 0):

For PDFBox **2.x** you'll need to use `contentStream.stroke()` in place of `contentStream.drawLine()`.

**Example:**

> contentStream.moveTo(xStart, yStart); 
> contentStream.lineTo(xEnd, yEnd);
> contentStream.stroke();

You can also set the stroke color using the `setStrokingColor` method.