# Why are my lines disappearing when I switch the deprecated drawLine() method for the version with moveTo / lineTo / stroke in Apache PDFBox 2.x?

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am creating a table by this example: http://fahdshariff.blogspot.de/2010/10/creating-tables-with-pdfbox.html

Now I've switched from Apache PDFBox 1.8 to 2.0, so some methods now are deprecated, including the `drawLine()`-method.

The [API changelog states](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/javadocs/deprecated-list.html) that you have to use a combination of 3 other methods now to accomplish the task of drawing a line:

```
org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream.drawLine(float, float, float, float):
Use PDPageContentStream.moveTo(float, float) 
followed by PDPageContentStream.lineTo(float, float) 
followed by PDPageContentStream.stroke()
```

Therefore I've changed this line

```
final float tableWidth = page.findMediaBox().getWidth() - (2 * margin);
```

to this line:

```
final float tableWidth = page.getMediaBox().getWidth() - (2 * margin);
```

And changing these 2 lines

```
// draw the rows
contentStream.drawLine(margin, nexty, margin + tableWidth, nexty);
(...)
// draw the columns
contentStream.drawLine(nextx, y, nextx, y - tableHeight);
```

to this:

```
// draw the rows
contentStream.moveTo(margin, nexty);
contentStream.lineTo(margin, nexty);
contentStream.stroke();
(...)
// draw the columns
contentStream.moveTo(nextx, y - tableHeight);
contentStream.lineTo(nextx, y - tableHeight);
contentStream.stroke();
```

But if I do this, all the lines are gone and dont appear in the PDF:

[image: emptyLines]

Strangely, if I mix the deprecated `drawLine()`-method with the `moveTo / lineTo / stroke`-methods, I can get either the rows OR the columns:

```
// draw the rows
float nexty = y;
for (int i = 0; i <= rows; i++) {
    contentStream.drawLine(margin, nexty, margin + tableWidth, nexty);
    // contentStream.moveTo(margin, nexty);
    // contentStream.lineTo(margin, nexty);
    // contentStream.stroke();
    nexty -= rowHeight;
}

// draw the columns
float nextx = margin;
for (int i = 0; i <= cols; i++) {
    // contentStream.drawLine(nextx, y, nextx, y - tableHeight);
    contentStream.moveTo(nextx, y - tableHeight);
    contentStream.lineTo(nextx, y - tableHeight);
    contentStream.stroke();
    nextx += colWidth;
}
```

Has this result:

[image: rowLines]

Switching on the deprecated `drawLine`-method for the columns

```
// draw the rows
float nexty = y;
for (int i = 0; i <= rows; i++) {
    // contentStream.drawLine(margin, nexty, margin + tableWidth,
    // nexty);
    contentStream.moveTo(margin, nexty);
    contentStream.lineTo(margin, nexty);
    contentStream.stroke();
    nexty -= rowHeight;
}

// draw the columns
float nextx = margin;
for (int i = 0; i <= cols; i++) {
    contentStream.drawLine(nextx, y, nextx, y - tableHeight);
    // contentStream.moveTo(nextx, y - tableHeight);
    // contentStream.lineTo(nextx, y - tableHeight);
    // contentStream.stroke();
    nextx += colWidth;
}
```

has this result:

[image: columnLines]

So the maths behind this for drawin the lines seems to be okay. But somehow there is a side-effect I'm not understanding, so the lines disappear?

How can I switch the deprecated `drawLine`-method to a non-deprecated version?

The example-code is a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so if you want to test my problem, simply copy the example code from here into the editor of your choice: http://fahdshariff.blogspot.de/2010/10/creating-tables-with-pdfbox.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
contentStream.moveTo(margin, nexty);
contentStream.lineTo(margin, nexty);
contentStream.stroke();
```

Is a **Point**. It should be:

```
contentStream.moveTo(margin, nexty);
contentStream.lineTo(margin + tableWidth, nexty);
contentStream.stroke();
```

If you draw a *vertical* line, you have to respectively increment the y-coordinate:

```
contentStream.moveTo(nextx, y); 
contentStream.lineTo(nextx, y - tableHeight);
```

I suggest you make a little helper method like this:

```
private void drawLine( PDPageContentStream content, float xstart, float ystart, float xend, float yend ){
    content.moveTo(xstart, ystart); // moves "pencil" to a position
    content.lineTo(xend, yend);     // creates an invisible line to another position
    content.stroke();               // makes the line visible
}
```

Comment: You're right! I got confused by `moveTo`, thinking this would already move my point, `lineTo` then creates a line between the starting point and then this line get's stroked. The columns work also like your suggestion:     contentStream.moveTo(nextx, y);
    contentStream.lineTo(nextx, y - tableHeight); ... could you integrate this into your answer please? So the next person can directly use the correct version?

Comment: I've improved the deprecation notices for drawLine and addLine for the upcoming versions, so hopefully the next person will understand this better.

Comment: @Fildor How can I change the color of line generated from the drawLine function??

Comment: @KNDheeraj I honestly do not know. You may find a solution in PDFBox tutorials/manuals or you may ask a separate question. UPDATE: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45954129/982149

Comment: @Fildor I have seen that stackoverflow post, the problem is that it is impacting other lines not generated from drawLine method, so I want to change color of those created by drawLine method

Comment: @KNDheeraj You need to save the Color it had before, then change color, create the colored lines, then change color to the old value. If I have time, I'll amend the answer later today.